# Cannot delete a cookie with explicit domain when it has been created with default domain

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

I've got a website, let's call it `www.example.com` In that website there are two pages. One creates a cookie like this:

```
setcookie('daCookie', 'boo', 2000000000, '/', '', false, true);
```

And the other one tries to delete it like this:

```
setcookie('daCookie', '', 1, '/', 'www.example.com', false, true);
setcookie('daCookie', '', 1, '/', '.www.example.com', false, true);
```

Now, I **know** that the first script was called in context of `www.example.com`. If I use the browser's (Google Chrome in this case) developer tools, I can see that the cookie's domain is `www.example.com`. However the second call does not delete it. If I change it to the empty domain:

```
setcookie('daCookie', '', 1, '/', '', false, true);
```

Then it works. But I'd really like to specify the domain explicitly. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in the second call (explicitly passing the domain name), browsers may prefix the value with a dot (.) since its a domain.  Which is why that call does not delete the cookies that was set previously (not passing the $domain param.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - using `.www.example.com` also doesn't work. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Actually I tested on Lynx (since it prompts me setting the cookie), and it worked in both cases.  Let me debug sometime later.

Comment: I'm not surprised. It works for me on Opera too. But not on Chrome.

Comment: You were right after all, I just didn't understand you! :) Indeed, when I manually specified any kind of domain, the browser did prefix it with a dot (or, if it already started with a dot, the browser just left it like that). However, the key point is that the browser did NOT prefix it with a dot when the domain was unspecified. So setting the cookie resulted in a "www.example.com" domain, while my attempts of deleting it yielded ".www.example.com" domains - which is why it didn't delete it.

Comment: I found this out by poking around in Chrome's cookie stash.

Answer (score 0):

From the php manual, all examples (explicitly passing the domain) use this:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
```

Where explicitly passing the domain parameter it looks as though it's best to ignore the 'www.'

It also has this to say regarding the domain parameter:

> The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to
>   'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain
>   and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as
>   'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as
>   'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated »
>   RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

Comment: The main reason I want to delete that cookie is exactly _because_ it got set with the wrong domain. I accidentally left the domain field empty and now a lot of people have the cookie with 'www.example.com', which is overriding the proper 'example.com' cookie. So I want to delete the cookie from the 'www.example.com' domain, but leave the 'example.com' cookie intact.

Comment: setcookie('daCookie', '', time() - 3600, '/', 'www.example.com', false, true); You could give that a try

Comment: The only difference is the time. I already checked that my code sends a correct date/time for 1970. I doubt this will help any.

Comment: setcookie('daCookie', '', time() - 3600, '/', '.example.com', false, true); This is the last thing I can think of

Comment: That won't work on any browser, because the "evil" cookie is on "www.example.com" domain which will override the ".example.com" domain any day.

Comment: OK my one final last attempt :) can you not do this setcookie('daCookie', 'boo', time() - 3600, '/', '', false, true);

Comment: Since it wasnt set with explicit path, maybe it can be removed without explicit path?

Comment: Yes, that works, I wrote it in the original post. And it's the workaround I'm currently using - check if the person is using the 'www' domain, and if so, delete the cookie via an empty string. I guess it's not so bad; I think it even covers all my needs, but I still wonder WHY it doesn't work with an explicit domain.

Comment: @Vilx- I think perhaps your question should be reworded in a 'Why does this work but this doesn't...' fashion rather than a 'Cannot' - just to help others searching?